# Maximum number of $0$-$1$ vectors with a given rank

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, computer-science

Let $k\ge2$. The maximum number of $0$-$1$ (column) vectors of length $2k-1$ which make a rank $k$ matrix with no zero row nor two identical rows is $2^{k-1}+1$. (The rank is over the rationals.)

I have a computer-based proof for this statement, but I'm looking for a computer-free argument.

Answer (score 2):

A construction for the lower bound: take the matrix of rank $k-1$ with $2^{k-1}$ columns consisting of all $\{0,1\}$-combinations of the vectors $e_1+e_2, e_3+e_4 \dots, e_{2k-3}+e_{2k-2}$. Then add the column $e_1+e_3+e_5+\dots+e_{2k-1}$, which will increase the rank by $1$ and make all the rows distinct.

**Edit:** If the rank was computed over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the matrix with $2^k$ columns consisting of all $\{0,1\}$-combinations of the $k$ vectors above also has rank $k$ and no zero row or two identical rows:

\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1  
\end{pmatrix}